# Why am I getting undefined route in header Only and not in other components?

Tags: angular

Below is my google brand route. When I am in GoogleDetailComponent using,

```
this. paramsSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params=> {
  this.searchStr = params['id']; 
});
```

I am able to get the params['id'] but not in header using the same above code.

```
// Define the routes
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'google', component: GoogleComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'google home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'google pixel', component: PixelComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: GoogleDetailComponent },
      { path: '', component: GoogleHomeComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

Below is my GoogleComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google',
  template: `<rb-google-header></rb-google-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

export class GoogleComponent implements OnInit { 
  ngOnInit(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}
```

When I search for 'Google Pixel', I want to be able to highlight 'Google Pixel' in header when I am in Google Brand: /google/google pixel. I do not know how to highlight 'google pixel' if I am getting undefined route in header. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: your GoogleComponent exists in the parent router outlet where as your PixelComponent exists in the child router outlet. Try accessing the child router outlet from GoogleComponent with this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe()

Comment: I am still getting undefined. I solved it by implementing DoCheck, OnChanges, and by saving the current route in service. I will try your suggestion again later and maybe using firstChild is a better implementation.